# How to override some files

Tags: magento2.4

I'm trying to override the next files:

- `vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php`
- `vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php`

What path I need to create in a Module to override those files?

I tried

- app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php
- app/code/Vendor/Module/Magento_Backend/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php
- app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php
- app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Magento_Reports/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php

none work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about magento 2 basics, and as it might seems confusing when you start learning it...it end up being quite easy to deal with.

What you need to get information about is `di.xml` while (di lands for dependency injection). In that file you will be able to specify things like `preference` and `plugin` among other things which are 2 way to extend a core functionality.

Before and After plugin are meant to add a peace of logic at the start or the end of a method.
While preference are more like being overriding the whole class; which seems like what you are trying to do here.

here is an exemple of existing preference

`<preference for="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy" />`

The for argument takes the class you want to override and the type argument take the class you are overriding it with. The class name and path by itself in type is irrelevant but it's common to re-use the same path as the core class.

Then your custom class is nothing special, just be careful about using or not extend if you need it.
Be also aware that extending private methods or attributes won't work and you will have to define them again.

Comment: Thanks! very clear and explained.